# beaneditform tapestry css style

Tags: css, jsp, tapestry

I want to change the standard css style of the beaneditform but can't find the file (default.css) in eclipse or on my local computer?!

any ideas?

[image: default.css]

this folder assets is not existing in my workspace, where is this file default.css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is located in the Tapestry Core JAR in the `org.apache.tapestry5` package. Don't edit it, instead just override the values with your own CSS with a CSS selector that is at least equally specific.

This is also explained nicely in the [CSS/Default Stylesheet section of the docs](http://tapestry.apache.org/css.html#CSS-Defaultstylesheet).